# Why is the keyboard not showing when view loads?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have this code in my viewdidload:

```
[_txtName setDelegate:self];
[_txtName becomeFirstResponder];
_txtName.enabled = YES;
_txtName.text = @"";
```

But when my view loads, the keyboard does not show, any idea why?

_txtName is the UITextField

Comment: try moving the becomeFirstResponder code to viewDidAppear method..

Comment: You've asked 9 questions here, and you've never upvoted anything nor have you accepted any answers.  Please stop being a leech.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment by @lukya you should place the call to `becomeFirstResponder` in either `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`. If you place the call in `viewWillAppear:` the keyboard will be shown on screen when the view is shown. If you would like the keyboard to animate in from the bottom when the view appears you should put the call in `viewDidAppear:`.